# Wamp - Can not use another version of MySQL (v5.7.19 -> other version)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I use `WAMP 3.1.9` with `Apache 2.4.41` and `phpMyAdmin 4.9.0.1`

When I installed WAMP, I had `MySQL version 5.7.19`
I decided to install `MySQL 5.7.27` and `MySQL 8.0.17` ([link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Addons/Mysql/))

When I select another database version (5.7.27 or 8.0.17)
The verison is checked and the server restarted correctly

Yet on phpMyAdmin, there is always marked:

```
Server version: 5.7.19 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

And when I open the console from wamp: `MySQL> MySQL Console`
I have this:

[image]

How can I use version 8.0.17 by default in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: look in the configuration file config.inc.php for $cfg['Servers'] see here https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers

Comment: I do not know what modification to make, I just modify ``$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'`` to ``$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'`` but that did not change anything

Comment: $i is a number starting from **1** for every new server add increase the number

Comment: any resolution? I am also facing the same issue.